# how to make signup form in SuiteCRM to store user with passwords on the CRM

Tags: forms, authentication, crm, portal, suitecrm

I have suite CRM that need to have signup form to make users in it with low privilege

I wanna to have a form on my WordPress websites that used to input username email with a password to use in suite CRM login

Comment: Can you post detail about what you have tried and where you need help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you a developer?
SuiteCRM only supports Email to Case feature associated with Inbound Email, from there you can create a workflow to convert cases into users.
Either way is to make open entry point to capture leads or User, you need to code a lot making this open entry point secure.